# Eulerian graph in two color

Tags: graph-theory

How can we prove the Eulerian Map can be color in 2 colors. I know the Eulerian graph can be colored at most 4, which is Four color problem. But I have no idea how to prove into 2 colors. Anyone can help me do this? Thanks!

The Eulerian map at here is mean the Eulerian planar graph (so all the vertices have even degrees).

Comment: Just clarify the Eulerian Map. It should be clear now. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "Eulerian Map" you mean Eulerian planar graph, then you might be interested in the fact that

> A planar bipartite graph is dual to a planar Eulerian graph and vice versa. [[MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerianGraph.html)]

**Edit:**

Sketch of the proof:

- $G$ is bipartite
- every cycle of $G$ is even
- every simple cycle of $G$ is even
- every vertex of $G^d$ has even degree
- $G^d$ is Eulerian.

I hope this helps ;-)

Comment: I think if I want to use this "fact" I need to prove the graph is a bipartite graph before I move on to next step right?

Comment: @leaveJava Yep. I've added a sketch of the proof, see the edits.

Comment: *This is user @ibodi's comment, which they attempted to post as an edit. I am rejecting the edit and copying the comment here:*

It's is not true than every simple cycle is even. Take a look at this picture:
[eulerian cycle with odd simple cycle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW2yz.jpg)

Comment: @jgon Thank you for the note.

Comment: @ibodi I think you are talking about the implication "every vertex of $G^d$ has even degree $\implies$ every simple cycle of $G$ is even" and your picture presents graph $G$, is that correct? If yes, then there might be a confusion in the notation: $G^d$ is the dual graph of $G$. In your picture there is a triangular face, which would become a vertex of degree $3$ in the dual graph.